# Chrome extension | Getting Local Storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I tried to read all the local storage items, but I'm missing a lot of items.

I'ved tried this approach: (manifest 2.0)

```
chrome.storage.local.get(null, function (items) {
      console.log('localStorage: ', items);
    });
```

I get a list of 3 items when checking the dev tools "local storage" tab I see more than 20 items.

Comment: chrome.storage.local and localStorage are completely different.

Comment: Why are you using MV2 ? It's deprecated, see [Manifest V2 support timeline](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv2-sunset/)

Comment: @ThomasMueller client choice.

Comment: Devtools shows `localStorage` not `chrome.storage.local`.